# php count even numbers in an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I am trying to learn php, and the code for finding even numbers doesn't output anything, but I can't seem to find the error, can anybody find where I have made my stupid mistake? Here is the code:

```
<?php

/*this sets the array up with the data*/

$myarray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

/* this is the count to get the total number from my array */

$total = count($myarray);
?>

<h1>Display all even numbers</h1>
<ul>
<?php for ($i=1; $i < total; $i += 2): ?>
<li>The array element value is <?php echo $myarray[$i]; ?>. </li>
<?php endfor; ?>

</ul>
```

Thanks and if nobody wants to post an answer I understand new questions are frustrating.

thanks

Comment: you missed `$` sign for `total`

Comment: Also, the code you have will show the odd numbers, not even. You need to start $i at 2.

Comment: Keep in mind you're only looking at the position in the array, rather than the value.  If you had `array(3,3,3,5,7,6,6,6,5,1,0)` things would be quite different.  If you're interested in even *values* you'll need to examine each number.

When programming (and talking about programming problems) it pays to  be exacting in your terminology.

Comment: I see your point, that makes sense, would $number % 2 == 0 work? Stupid question, why is the number divisible by 2 == 0 for every value that is even?

Comment: You are aware that answer is available in phpDocs? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't *finding* even numbers. You're identifying their positions in the array, and printing values only for those indexes. Look at this php snippet.

```
<?php 
$myarray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
// Array indexes start at 0, not 1.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) { 
  echo "Index ", $i, ", value ", $myarray[$i], ": ";
  // A value is even if there's no remainder when you divide it by 2.
  if ($myarray[$i] % 2 == 0) {
    echo "even\n";
  }
  else {
    echo "odd\n";
  }
}
?>
```

Put that in a file, and run it through php. You should see this.

```
Index 0, value 1: odd
Index 1, value 2: even
Index 2, value 3: odd
Index 3, value 4: even
Index 4, value 5: odd
Index 5, value 6: even
Index 6, value 7: odd
Index 7, value 8: even
Index 8, value 9: odd
Index 9, value 10: even
```

This shorter version will print only the even values.

```
<?php 
$myarray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for ($i=0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) { 
  if ($myarray[$i] % 2 == 0) {
    echo "Index ", $i, ", value ", $myarray[$i], "\n";
  }
}
?>

Index 1, value 2
Index 3, value 4
Index 5, value 6
Index 7, value 8
Index 9, value 10
```

Comment: Ok now that makes perfect sense thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `$` variable creator in your `for loop` for `total`:

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i < $total; $i += 2): ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code fits your problem.

```
 <?php

   $myarray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
   $total = count($myarray);
   echo "<h1>Display all even numbers</h1>";
                  echo "<ul>";

             foreach($myarray as $rw)
             {
              if(($rw%2) == 0 ){
              echo "<li>".$rw."</li>";
              }
             }
             echo "</ul>";
  ?>
```

The modulus operator `%` is the best way to get the odd or even numbers in an array.

Answer (score 0):

printing a even number in php. there `$a`is 20 when you run this code the out put is 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20,

```
$a = 20 
  for ($i=0; $i < $a; $i += 2)
            {               
            echo "</n><br>".$i;
            }
```

Out put like this

2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20